# Lambda expression and class method

Tags: c#, class, lambda, expression

I have a problem like this.

```
List<Absent> absent = new List<Absent>();
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
Console.Write("Please enter a full name> ");
string temp_str = Console.ReadLine();


absent.Where(x => x.Name == temp_str).Run(x = x.WriteConsoleTable());
```

How can I run a method after doing a filtering?
Absent is a Class which has a *Name* variable and *WriteConsoleTable* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the `ForEach` extension method but you'll first need to call `ToList` on the `IEnumerable` sequence returned from the `Where` clause.

```
absent.Where(x => x.Name == temp_str)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x => x.WriteConsoleTable());
```

or you can iterate over the collection using the `foreach` construct.

i.e.

```
foreach (var item in absent.Where(x => x.Name == temp_str))
        item.WriteConsoleTable();
```

Comment: Yes, I had some search before writing this post, but after *Where* there's no *ForEach*.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, I see. Working Perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Right, if you're looking for only a single match then as the other answer has suggested you _should_ utilise `FirstOrDefault` or even `SingleOrDefault` depending on your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options.

```
var absences = absent.Where(x => x.Name == temp_str);
foreach(var abs in absences)
{
    abs.WriteConsoleTable();
}
```

or if you are sure you only need first match

```
var absence = absent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == temp_str);
if(absence != null)
{
    absence.WriteConsoleTable();
}
```

Comment: It looks like working. `absent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == temp_str).WriteConsoleTable();` I used like this, because I know there should be data. Thanks!